Externalize csv as BQ table with autodetect false and schema provided
I am trying to find the right syntax to set autodetect to false and read the schema for a table from a json file.
Use Case: I have 500+ files that are processed and converted to a few csv files. This is then externalized in Big Query based on the date extracted as a partition. Ideally if all the columns are strings this would work fine without a schema. With BQ determining the field type based on the first 100 columns, it errors out since some columns are detected as INTEGERS when they are not. I am using DBT to externalize my files. Below is a sample yml.
tables:
- name: base_test
external:
autodetect: false
schema: test_schema.json
location: 'to csv'
options:
format: CSV
hive_partition_uri_prefix: 'csv_folder'
partitions:
- name: date_extracted
data_type: string
What are my options to externalize a csv output with all column data type as strings to a BQ table?
I added autodetect and schema to the yml file. The table generate with Auto-detect schema set to true.
Also tried to set the datatype to string on generating the csv. This did not have any effect.
